# Moving camera in-game: causing some sort of uneasiness

Tags: graphics-card, graphics

This is not a question about a specific game, but I am wondering if anyone has something that can shed some light on this - it is gaming related.

I am using a `MSI PULSE GL76` laptop to play my games - it is a good mid-tier gaming laptop.

Now - some games that I play are not causing some discomfort/uneasiness for me, while some do, it is sort of a "butterflies in the stomach", sea-sick/car-sick feeling, almost like playing a mobile phone game while driving in a car (of course not while **I** am the driver, heh...). Motion sickness?

Some games that do not cause this feeling for me:

- A Plague Tale: Requiem
- A Plague Tale: Innocence
- Control: Ultimate Edition

A game that does cause this feeling for me:

- The Last of Us: Part 1

The games look similar in camera view - third person view, vast worlds, colorful scenery, etc., but the one that causes me some discomfort appears to have some effect in the peripheral when rotating the camera view, first straining my eyes badly, and then causes this sea-sick feeling.

`Maid of Sker` and `Martha is Dead` gave me a similar feeling, the former much more severe than the latter, but neither of them anywhere NEAR the degree of `The Last of Us: Part 1`, even though they are first-person games, not third-person. In the past, I also got a similar feeling when jumping down from a high building in `Thief 4`. I even got this when falling in `Minecraft`. That did not bother me, as it was occasionally only when I drop down something - but in this game, it is all the time, not only when dropping.

I can't see myself completing the game if I can't change this, even though I like the story line so far. After only about 10 minutes of play, I need to stop and take a break.

If we assume this is a form of motion-sickness (if someone has a better description, please enlighten me), is there some setting in games that are affecting me that I can set (providing a game supports it of course). What I mean "if the game supports it" is simply - could this disappear if I change detail setting of a game, up or down the frame rate, switch anisotropic settings, etc.? I am counting on other gamers' experiences here - not a medical answer, of course.

Any ideas would be great, as I would love to continue The Last of Us: Part 1.

**EDIT:**

I learned since that it is indeed a "thing" but - the recommendations are "well-lit, well-ventilated room" and "sit further back from the screen" etc. - While all of this make sense, it does not make sense why some games do this and others don't, in the exact same environment. I even tested now whether it is related to how I feel in the moment: Still, the games that do not do this still do not, and The Last of Us: Part 1 still does it - so not a "my current mood/condition" thing. Another suggestion is "take medicine for it" and I am not liking that idea.

**EDIT 2:**

I also got this from https://kidshealth.org/en/teens/simulator-sickness.html: Doctors aren't sure exactly why video games cause motion sickness. They think it might have to do with mismatched messages about movement that the brain gets from the eyes and inner ears. Liquid in the semicircular canals of your inner ear allows you to sense if you're moving. But the brain can get confused if your inner ear senses that you're sitting still while your eyes see the action on the screen and tell the brain you're moving. That may leave you feeling sick, dizzy, or drowsy.

Comment: Is motion blur on (if there is such a setting in LoU:P1)?

Comment: Yeah, motion blur is a good thing to check, as are chromatic aberrations, and definitely depth of field settings. But I'm wondering if FOV (Field of View) settings can cause eye strain, as I think I've experienced mild motion sickness based on those. Can you check your settings in those games?

Comment: Thank you @DrFish, I will check for motion blur next time I play.

Comment: And thank you @Joachim - I will check for FOV and Chromatic Aberrations. :-) If any of these exist and make a difference, I'll let you know.

Comment: Somewhere on like Physics or Graphic Design (or here?) there's a really good break down for this, but I can't find it ;\ .... Something about there being other stuff you can focus on in the distance in the room, like when you sit 3' from a 12" screen (way too far away actually). In front of you is motion, but the room isn't moving = puke. - I'm 3' from a *4'* screen; never happens. Basically VR w/o goggles.

Comment: You getting pretty good FPS? The better it looks, the harder the time your brain is going to have reconciling that little screen moving, and the rest of the room not. Took about 2 weeks to get used to being that close, and at 120hz makes it kinda crazy too. Get a mouse, a keyboard, a monitor, *a desk*, and join the club ;)

Comment: @Mazura - I have actually not checked this game specifically, but most games I get more than 30 FPS. Thanks. I will investigate and check.